# Improving cleaning of CMake build directory

Tags: build, cmake, organization

I'm trying to figure out a way to configure my CMake build to include a "clean" target that will remove all files in the build directory except for those in a subdirectory named "modules".

Why, you may ask? Well, our codebase is currently makefile based and I'm switching it to cmake. My current setup is to add a cmake/ directory at the top level that includes required macros in the modules/ subfolder. People can then run "cmake .." from the cmake/ directory.

Often when I make changes in my CMakeLists.txt I want to be absolutely sure none of my previous cmake runs hold influence, so it's good to start from scratch in the cmake/ directory. I can't just rm -rf ./ since there is the required modules/ directory. I want a simple "cmake clean" way of restoring it, if possible.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I'd view your /cmake/modules files as part of your source tree, and would create a separate empty "build" directory - either in the root of your project or leave it to users to create outside the root.  That way, your sources don't get mixed up with your build files.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. Maybe it's just a personal preference, or a relic thought process from the in-source makefiles, but I like the idea of doing it all within the cmake/ directory, even if it contains a source controlled modules/ directory.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this in some of my codes.  At the bottom of my `CMakeLists.txt` I add the line

```
# Add a distclean target to the Makefile
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(distclean COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/distclean.cmake)
```

I then add a file called `distclean.cmake` in my top level directory.  This file contains a loop over files I want to delete:

```
# Loop over the directories/files and delete each one
FOREACH(D ${DEL}) # DEL is a list of the directories and files to delete
    IF(EXISTS ${D})
        FILE(REMOVE_RECURSE ${D})
    ENDIF()
ENDFOREACH()
```

You can take a look at my full `distclean.cmake` file [here](https://github.com/SethMMorton/NPSpec/blob/master/distclean.cmake).